# Select items from categories and item should also be in another category

Tags: mysql

i have one issue which i'm unable to solve.

The problem is with sql query i need to select items from categories which should also be in another category.
basically it is something like this :

```
select * from items where category_id in (1,2,3,4,5) and category_id = 6
```

of course above statement will not work, i have tried to:

```
select * from items where category_id in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
GROUP BY item_id HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT category_id) > 1
```

but this will give me also items which are exist in multiple categories  like items which exist in category 1, category 2 and in category 3, but not in category 6.

any suggestion on how to solve this issue.

Comment: If you mean that the data should be in all the given category `(1,2,3,4,5,6)` then you should have `HAVING COUNT(*) = 6`

Comment: not in all. that is the problem i  have item which is in category 1, 2 and in 6.

also i have item which is in 1,3 and in 6.  and i have item which is in 1,2 and in 3

i need to get only those items that will be in any of the category but also in category 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to filter the resulting groups, by counting the number of constituent records that match each of your criteria and combining with suitable logical operations:

```
SELECT   item_id
FROM     items
WHERE    category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5,6) -- only for performance, if indexed
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING   SUM(category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5))
     AND SUM(category_id = 6)
```

Another way would be to use a self-join, with each side of the join filtering the groups according to a different criterion:

```
SELECT   item_id
FROM     items a JOIN items b USING (item_id)
WHERE    a.category_id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
     AND b.category_id = 6
GROUP BY item_id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, with sum i get results but not sure if i get all items back.

will have to test it. original query is really complex with joins already.